# How to upload an image with two different names in input tag with PHP? And resize them

Tags: php

To upload the image I tried the single image upload code twice but it is not properly uploading both the images. The first one is uploaded and the second one is not.
Here is the code for the Form i used:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
<tr><td>Title</td><td><input type="text" name="title" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Date</td><td><input type="text" name="date" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Thumbnail</td><td><input type="file" name="thumb" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Image</td><td><input type="file" name="image" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Details</td><td><textarea name="details"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: your html is valid and correct. Are you sure that your script handle this form data correctly?
you can check it with print_r() function: print_r($_FILES)

Comment: nothing seems to be wrong here. Definitely something is wrong with your PHP code!

Comment: yeah there was a small error in my script as for the location and just got the solution with changing the locations of both the files to be uploaded.

Comment: yes boss... there was a PHP script error.. thanx

Comment: Anyway you can check globals `$_POST` `$_GET` `$_FILES` with `print_r()` function to print them. Its very useful for me... hope it will be useful for you too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In your HTML page use:**

```
<input type="file" name="image[thumb]" />
<input type="file" name="image[image]" />
```

**And in PHP catch it this way:**

```
$_FILES['image']['thumb'];
$_FILES['image']['image'];
```

Cheers!

Comment: this has absolutely no benefit over the code from the question

Comment: Strange! The solution is an accepted one, and you are saying that "this has absolutely no benefit"!

Answer (score 4):

To re-size the uploaded image you can try this code:-

```
function getWidth() {

return imagesx($this->image);
}
function getHeight() {

return imagesy($this->image);
}


function resize($width,$height) {
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
$this->image = $new_image;
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer this solution, it's easier for the user (and better practice) to only upload one file and generate the thumbnail for it on the server. Not every user is able to use a graphics program to resize an image file.